# Export a portion of PHP generated content to HTML files in zip folder

Tags: php, html, zip, export

I have a php wiki that a customer would like to export a php wiki for use by their customers on local environments without access to the internet.  I envision a php script that will export the php to HTML, store it in some folders and then zip it up and make it available for download.

I am wondering if there is a script or framework out there already that encapsulates the functionality before I go recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to take static pages, you could use a downloader like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), which allows you to create a static web site for offline use.  It would still show editor features, but because there is no code on the end, it wouldn't work.  Do you want this as a one time thing, or do you want your php scripts to update this "zip" realtime/nightly?

Comment: Yeah I thought of HTTrack as an option, I was wondering if there was a PHP version that had the same functionality so I could configure it and make it possible for the user to export from a control panel ("at the push of a button").  I think it could be done with cURL and a HTML DOM parser, but I wanted to see if anyone had anything like this that already existed.